# Динамические структуры

Tags: структуры-данных, visual-c++

Доброго времени суток.
Начал изучать структурки в плюсах, но возникли проблемки!
Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь вводил данные, потом увидел весь список и так до тех пор, пока не захочет выйти! Вроде по логике написал все правильно, но программа летит (видимо, проблема с памятью).
Помогите, пожалуйста.  ))

```
#include "stdafx.h"

struct Mystruct
{
    string Name;
    int age;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int size=1;
    Mystruct* pStr = new Mystruct[size];

    int exit=0;

    while (exit != 1)
    {
        cout <<"size= " <<size<<endl;
        cout << "Enter name of a new human: ";
        cin >>pStr[size-1].Name;
        cout << "Enter age of a new human: ";
        cin >>pStr[size-1].age;

        cout <<endl << "Data of people:" <<endl;
        for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << i+1 << " human name: " << pStr[i].Name <<endl;
            cout << i+1 << " human age: " << pStr[i].age <<endl;
            cout << "-----------------------" <<endl<<endl;

        }

        cout << "Do you want exit from program?" <<endl;
        cout << "1-Yes, 2-No" <<endl;
        cin >> exit;
        if (exit == 1)
            break;
        size++;
    }

    delete[] pStr;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что Вы создали структуру Mystruct размером в 1 элемент (size = 1).
Следовательно, выходя за пределы индекса ( >0 ), идет обращение к неопределенному\защищенному блоку памяти. Задайте сразу допустимый размер массива элементов и заполняйте его значениями.